# Does mpi4py's gather create a list with elements matching ranks?

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am using mpi4py in a program. 
I run the program with n>1 cores and each core has its own list (which we can call "core_specific_list" of numbers. 
I want the rank 0 core to collect all the lists in one big list, that we can call "big_list".

I start the program with (just to define the variables):

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
```

So, to make the big list do this, I let each core call:

```
big_list = comm.gather(core_specific_list, root = 0)
```

This *does* create the big_list as expected (where each element is one of the other ranks' core_specific_list). And it also seems like each list element is in order of the rank who sent it (that is, element 0 of big_list is the core_specific_list of rank 0, etc.).

**Question:** But is this assumption correct? That is, is element j in big_list the core_specific_list of rank j? (I understand that I can test this on some cases like I did, but I need to make absolutely sure that I can rely on this assumption)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely rely on that behaviour since that's exactly how the `MPI_GATHER` call (wrapped by `comm.gather`) works. From §5.5 of the MPI standard:

> The root process receives the messages and stores them in rank order.
>
> ...
>
> An alternative description is that the `n` messages sent by the processes in the group are concatenated in rank order, and the resulting message is received by the root as if by a
>   call to `MPI_RECV(recvbuf, recvcount·n, recvtype, ...)`.